# How can I make ORMLITE persist/load an Interface using the implementing class?

Tags: java, android, orm, ormlite

I have the following classes (simplified for clarity)

```
@DatabaseTable
public class CourseImpl implements Course, Foo, Bar
{
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    private Collection<Resource> resources;
}
```

and

```
@DatabaseTable
public class ResourceImpl implements Resource, Baz, Qux
{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private UUID id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false, index = true, columnName = PARENT_ID)
    private Course parent;
}
```

I'm interested in holding a collection of ResourceImpl instances in the CourseImpl class, and have them connect automatically.

However currently I get an exception

> *No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in interface **Course***

I got it to stop complaining by switching `private Course parent` to `private CourseImpl parent`.

However, I would ***really*** like to use interfaces instead of actual implementation classes, to keep code clean, and hide the implemented `Foo`,`Bar`, and `Baz` interface contracts in this context.

Is there a way I can tell ORMLite to look for the fields in the implementation class?
If so - how do I go about it?

Comment: The problem is that you are asking ORMLite to maintain a relationship which requires it to know the `id` field of the `Course`.  But that is an interface and _not_ a implementation class.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Could I write a custom dao which would cast Course to CourseImp?

I would prefer a way to specify the implementing class, similar to how one would specify a non-default dao.

Comment: But what's the difference between specifying `CourseImp` as opposed to configuring it in the annotation or something.  Why not use `CourseImp` but only expose a `Course` via the public getters on the object?  ORMLite requires strong object linkage here.

Comment: Also couldn't you do .getClass() on the field at runtime, to dynamically select a dao?

Comment: Well there are a couple of issues:
(a) I don't want Course to know of the rest of the functions ResourceImpl implements as part of Baz and Qux interfaces. 
(b) What about putting two different implementations in a collection, and each being saved to the appropriate table?